# variance of quadratic forms when the random variables are not normally distributed

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, quadratic-forms, independence, variance

Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix and $X = (X_1,...,X_n)^T$ a vector of independent identically distributed random variables. The random variables are assumed not to be normally distributed.

What ist the variance of the quadratic form $x^T A x$, i.e.

$Var(x^T A x) =  ?$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: The formula given on page 10 in "Linear Regression Analysis" by George A. F. Seber, Alan J. Lee and the formula on page 57 in "Linear Models" by Searle, but the calculated variance differs much from the simulated variance.
The second one seems to hold only for the normal distribution.

Comment: if you want to know why they are different, then you might want to post that as a question.

Answer (score 1):

Writing $X^T A X = \sum_{i,j} A_{ij} X_i X_j$, we have
$$ \text{Var}(X^T A X) = \sum_{i,j,k,l} A_{ij} A_{kl} \text{Cov}(X_i X_j, X_k X_l)$$
The covariance is $0$ if $\{i,j\}$ and $\{k,l\}$ are disjoint, but all the other terms are potentially nonzero.  You'll have to consider various cases.  Without knowing anything about the distribution of the $X_i$, there's not much more that can be said.